# Cloud Dataflow: Once trigger not working

Tags: triggers, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Dataflow pipeline reading from unbounded source. My window size is 10 hours, I am trying to test my trigger using a TestStream. My trigger will emit early result if element count reaches at least 2 for the same key within a Window. I have following trigger to achieve this:

```
input.apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(12)))              .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
        .withEarlyFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(2)))
        .apply(Count.perElement())
```

We also tried:

```
Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(2)).orFinally(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())
```

I expect early firing when asserting the result, however I don't get all the result in

```
 PAssert.that(pipeline).inWindow(..)..
```

What am I doing wrong? Also running same test repeatedly yields different result meaning different values are returned from the trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggering is non-deterministic. It will give you an early firing some time after the trigger condition is satisfied. It will then give you another early firing some time after the trigger condition is satisfied again.

The actual choice to emit after the trigger is determined by the runner. If you are using a batch runner, it may wait until all the data is available. How much input are you expecting for each key/window? Which runner are you using?

Comment: This was in context of TestStream. It is working now. Thanks for the information.